# JPQL IN operator in DELETE query with 2-deep relationship WHERE clause

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a JPQL query like this :

```
    @Modifying
    @Query("delete from Thing t where t.manyToOne1.manyToOne2 = :farThing and t.id in :ids")
    void delete(ManyToOne2 manyToOne2, List<String> ids);
```

Resulting in an exception :

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cross join many_to_one1 manytoone1_ where manytoone2_id=1039 and (id in (' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the request to

```
    @Modifying
    @Query("delete from Thing t where t.manyToOne1 = :manyToOne1 and t.id in :ids")
    void delete(ManyToOne1 manyToOne1, List<String> ids);
```

fixes the issue.

It seems that there is theoretically nothing wrong with using 2-deep many-to-one relationship chain for some other requests, but combining with the `IN` operator or maybe with a modifying query just doesn't work in practice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that this kind of query uses an implicit join which would generate a SQL join in a DML statement. This is not allowed for all DBMS and there is no support in Hibernate for this yet. As you figured out, you can avoid the implicit join. For delete statements, you could also use an exists subquery to model joins, something like this:

```
delete from Thing t 
where t.id in :ids
  and exists (
    select 1 
    from t.manyToOne1 a
    where a.manyToOne2 = :farThing
)
```